# Ember issue with setting attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember Route class defined as below;

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var compObj = {};
        compObj.gridPara = this.get('gridPara');
        return compObj;
    },
    gridPara: function() {
        var self = this;
        var returnObj = {};
        returnObj.url = '/myService';
        // setting some other returnObj attributes
        var summaryObj = {
            total: {
                label: "Total 1",
                value: "100"
            },
            additional: [{
                label: 'Label 2',
                value: 'val2'
            }, {
                label: 'Label 3',
                value: 'val3'
            }]
        };
        returnObj.summary = summaryObj;
        return returnObj;
    },
    actions: {
        dataLoaded: function(resp) {
            // Here I get the service response and want to set (or overwrite) the summaryObj values
            this.get('gridParams').summary.total.value = resp.numRows;          
        }
    }
});
```

My template looks like

```
{{my-grid params=this.gridPara dataLoaded="dataLoaded"}}
```

Now I want to set the "summary" on returnObj
I have verified that I get "resp" inside dataLoaded callback.

But I get the following error when trying to do

```
this.get('gridParams').summary.total.value = resp.numRows;
```

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `value` property (of [object Object]) to `100`.

Also how do I set/push for "additional" array inside summaryObj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you must use `set` to the the value (Im assuming you have gridParams defined somewhere?):

```
this.set('gridParams.summary.total.value', resp.numRows);
```

In order to push a new object, try this:

```
var additional = this.get('gridParams.additional');
additional.push({label: ..., value: ....});
this.set('gridParams.additional', additional);
```

Comment: Thx..Just one more question...How do I update any existing value inside this "additional" array...Say I want to update the 1st item's (or if possible one with certain label value) 'value' to "NEW_VAL" ?

So I do not want to keep on pushing, but update an existing array item

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure, but give it a try:

- Watch out the property names. I suppose it's a wording error to declare 'gridPara' and trying to get 'gridParams'
- You should retrieve the value like this
  `this.get('gridParams.summary.total.value')`
- What you are trying with the last sentence is a setting, but like it was plain JS. In Ember you should do it `this.set('gridParams.summary.total.value',resp.numRows)`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @Remi answers ,the best practice would be to use

```
Ember.set('gridParams.summary.total.value', resp.numRows);
```

To answer the question in your comment
Say you want to update `additional`  array at index `i`.Just do

```
var updateItem = additional[i];
Ember.set(updateItem.propertyname,newValue)
//Here propertyname would be the property you want to update and new Value is the new value which you want to set to that property
```